# Have one object's variables to be pointing to another object's variable in Java

Tags: java, pointers, mapping

My example is quite concrete as I make a system of students and courses objects. each courses have a list of students and their grades, I'm looking for an efficient way to connect those two.

Currently my Student object has:

```
public class student {
    String studentName;
    String[] courses;
```

And my course Object has:

```
public class course {
    String courseName;
    Map<String, Integer> studentGrade = new HashMap<>(); // where string is student names and int is their grade
```

But instead of a string array in my student object, to have a variable that would **point** to my mapping maybe? Any tips appreciated.

Also I'm assuming keeping it this way is quite bad as I always have to chagce both objects whenever anything happens.

Comment: Why do you not give each `Student` a field of type `Course` or `List<Course>`?

Comment: Consider not using the student name as lookup key because students could have the same name. Make each student have a unique id instead and use that or the Student object with implemented equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using a database.

In this matter, you can either keep a `courseList` for each `student`, or you can keep a `studentList` for each `course`.

For the first solution, you simply define a list of `courses` for a `student` object.

For the second one, you can only keep a list instead of a map.

Or you can write a third method in which you map each course to a list of its students, meaning:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> courseStudentMap = new HashMap()<>;
```

In all cases, whenever anything changes, you need to manually take care of it, and no way around this matter.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do next:

```
public class student {
    String studentName;
    Map<String, Integer> studentGrade = new HashMap<>();// the key is courseName

public class course {
    String courseName;
    list<student> = new ArrayList<>();
```

or you also can do that

```
public class course {
        String courseName;
        list<String> = new ArrayList<>(); //the key is studentName
```